# Multiple threads run in parallel? No GIL limitation?

Tags: python

The following code takes only 2 seconds when 10 requests are requested at the same time (`ab -n 10 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:5000/`). Shouldn't it be 10 seconds because of GIL?

```
from flask import Flask
from time import sleep

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    sleep(1)
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

# ab -n 10 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:5000/
# This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3

# Server Software:        Werkzeug/2.0.1
# Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
# Server Port:            5000

# Concurrency Level:      10
# Time taken for tests:   2.021 seconds
# Complete requests:      10
```

Is `sleep()` blocking? And the code doesn't use asyncio even if it yields the control when calling `sleep()`?

Comment: I don't know a lot about the GIL, but I would think that while one (or several) threads are sleeping, that is the perfect situation for other threads to get work done.

Comment: Is `sleep()` blocking? And the code doesn't use asyncio if it yield the control when calling `sleep()`?